# Replacing a searching character in Char array by its index value if it is found

Tags: java, arrays, char

// here i am try to find the location of a char in char array.
if character is resent in the array replace it's original value by its index that is an integer. but when i am try to compile it i got some non- printable out put.so please help me. i mean , when i try access the array element then effect of above operation must be seen.

```
class Re{

  public static void main(String [] args)

  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String enter = input.nextLine();
    char [] array = enter.toCharArray();
    char find = input.next().charAt(0);
    char find2 = Character.toUpperCase(find);
    char find3 = Character.toLowerCase(find); 
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
      if((find2==array[i])|| ( find3==array[i]))
      {
        array[i] =  (char)(i);
      }
      else
      {
         array[i] =array[i];
       }
    }

    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
      {
         System.out.print(array[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode has a lot of non-printable characters. See [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the ones you are probably getting (first 127 characters of UTF-16 are same as ASCII). If you want to convert an integer to its corresponding character value what you can do is add `'0'` to it.

Ex:

```
if (find2 == array[i] || find3 == array[i]) {
    array[i] = (char)(i + '0');

} // omit your else self-assignment, it is redundant
```

If i > 9 then it is not convertable to a numerical character (only single digit) so you would have to use Strings.

Ex:

```
String[] out = new String[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == findUp || array[i] == findLo) {
        out[i] = String.valueOf(i);
    } else {
        out[i] = String.valueOf(array[i]);
    }
}
```

You can also use [Character#forDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29) in the form of `Character.forDigit(i, 10)` which either returns the above expression (`'0' + digit`), an alphabetical character if the digit is > 9 `('a' + digit - 10)` or a null character if the digit is outside the radix. IE `Character.forDigit(10, 10)` returns a null character but `Character.forDigit(10, 16)` (hex) returns `'a'`.

When you cast between char and primitive number types (int, short, etc) what you are working with is the Unicode codepoint. For example `(char)9` is actually the tab character. Unicode numbers correspond to codes 48-57. Because the numbers are contiguous (0 corresponds to 48, 1 corresponds to 49, 2 corresponds to 50, etc) you can add the value of `'0'` and get the corresponding character. For example `48 + 2 = 50` so `'0' + 2 = '2'`. Due to algebra you can also of course convert a character to an integer by subtraction IE `'2' - '0' = 2`.

Comment: Or use Character.forDigit(i, 10).

Comment: suppose i have {i, a,m,a,n,u,r,a,g,p,a,n,d,a,y} a char array, so if i want to search 'a' , then it is present at 1,3,7,10,and 13th place so i want all 'a' is replaced with it's index . and out put should be like {i ,1,m,3,u,r,7,g,p,10,n,d,13,y}

Comment: These examples will do that for you then. I added a paragraph to my answer that explains why. If you want to go past 9 (include 10, 13, etc) you'll have to use Strings.

Comment: thank you sir i get short out my problem . so thanks a lot for giving me a valuable information

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this:

```
    if ((find2 == array[i]) || (find3 == array[i])) {
        array[i] = find;
    } 
    else {
        array[i] = array[i];
   }
```

Comment: This will just reassign the entire array to itself or change the case.

Comment: It's okey. Array and 'find' have this same type - char.